# Is there a way I can search URL's on Google/Bing verbatim with dots?

Tags: search

I'm trying to do some security related research with Google but it filters out `.` and fuzzy matches across the whole page. Is there a search engine that will let me do exact in-URL matching?

Comment: google hacking might help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_hacking

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can “tell” the Google web search app how to interpret your input.

- Literal search: you can use `"` to enclose a literal string to search for, like `"BandIsBand"`
- Domain Search: you can use is `site:<domain or URL>`. This can limit the results to only include the site/domain you specify. Like `banana Site:stackexchange.com`

---

Some Googlefu Links:

- [Search operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433)
- [Advanced Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/35890)

Comment: I tried that but it won't let me find say `.editorconfig` in the URL only.

Comment: what is your search string?

Comment: I'm not actually searching for a particular domain, I'm searching for URLs. For example: `http://www.google.com/foo/bar/.test/foo` I want to find URLs that contain `.test`.

Comment: I do not think google lets you search specificly for URL parts. but you can just search for the ```.text``` and add some context to the like ```wordpress``` to try and find wordpress sites with a .config.